# UWP-Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) at Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register()

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Exception while using

```
BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = taskBuilder.Register();
```

Exception:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    at Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register()

My Code snippet

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
SmsMessageReceivedTrigger trigger = new SmsMessageReceivedTrigger(filterRules);
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "SmsBackgroundTask.SampleSmsBackgroundTask";
taskBuilder.Name = "SampleSmsBackgroundTask";
BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = taskBuilder.Register();
```

appxmanifest:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" 
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" 
         xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
         IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">`

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="cellularMessaging" />
  </Capabilities>

</Package>
```

also there is a warning at `<rescap:Capability Name="cellularMessaging" />`

warning:

> The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities'

Referred [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive/cs) link for creation of my background task.

Comment: Well, the runtime error seems almost certainly a result of your flawed manifest. I don't know for sure what the right declaration is, but it appears that `"cellularMessaging"` is supported in the `Capability` element. Why are you using the `rescap:Capability` element there? [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) are a bit confusing, but it describes `"cellularMessaging"` simply as a "capability" and not a "restricted capability".

Comment: Only `"cellularDeviceControl"` is described as "restricted" (under the cellular list) and so I'd expect only that capability to be in the `rescap:` namespace. Have you tried just removing the namespace (i.e. removing `rescap:` from the element declaration)?

Comment: After removing 'rescap:' getting error: 'Error  Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 39, Column 17, Reason: 'cellularMessaging' violates enumeration constraint of 'internetClient internetClientServer privateNetworkClientServer allJoyn codeGeneration'. The attribute 'Name' with value 'cellularMessaging' failed to parse.'